# How to understand ideals in $F$, which is a finite commutative ring with $1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, finite-rings

I do not fully understand about ideals in finite rings, and I have to choose the correct answer to the following:

If $F$ is a finite commutative ring with $1,$ then

(i) Each prime ideal is a maximal
ideal.

(ii) $F$ has no nontrivial maximal
ideal.

(iii) $F$ may have a prime ideal which
is not maximal.

(iv) $F$ is a field.

I know that $(\mathbb{Z}_6,+,.)$ is a finite commutative ring with $1$ which is not a field so (iv) is out. I have no idea about other options as I have never seen an ideal of a finite ring. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hint: what is the relationship between prime ideals, maximal ideals, integral domains, and fields? What do you know about finite integral domains?

Comment: $\{0, 2, 4\}$ is an ideal in $\mathbb Z_6$, the image of $2\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @countinghaus  $R$ be a ring and $I$ be an ideal of $R$ then $I$ is maxiaml iff $R/I$ is field, and prime iff $R/I$ is an integral domain

Comment: @TaxiDriver - I edited the question and the title - I hope this is OK. You will see from the answers that you can do the whole question using general principles. I put a comment about an ideal in the ring you cited as an example. $\mathbb Z_n$ is a source of further examples (where $n$ is composite, this is a ring, not a field).

Comment: @MarkBennet I am simply pleased and delihted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example has nontrivial maximal ideals, so (ii) is also out.

Now recall that an ideal $I$ of the unital ring $F$ is prime if and only if $F/I$ is a domain, and maximal if and only if $F/I$ is a field. Now apply something you should know about finite domains.

Comment: Andreassssssssssssssss Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1) A finite integral domain is a field ;

2) Fields have *only* one ideals which is maximal: the trivial one $\,\{0\}\,$ ;

(3) Re-read (1)

Comment: Don thank youuuuuuuuu